# Проблема с русскими символами в строке в NetBeans

Tags: java

Пытаюсь написать программу на Java. Ее смысл: должна быть введена текстовая переменная (название месяца). Пользователь вводит возможные варианты, а программа говорит, угадал он или нет. Подскажите, какой тип должна иметь загаданная переменная?

Пробовала `String s = "Апрель"`, но компилятор не только меняет слово "Апрель" на непонятные знаки, но еще и выдает что-то об открытом типе литерала.

Comment: а пробовали на анлийском, может с кодировкой что-то?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 11):

**1-й способ:**

Ваша проблема описана [**тут**](http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.9.php).

Если вы пишете в NetBeans, например, то вам необходимо зайти в свойства проекта и поменять кодировку на `windows-1251`.
После этого данный код работает корректно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Введите месяц:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

---

**2 способ:**

Указать кодировку вводимых символов сразу:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"Cp1251"));
    System.out.println("Введите месяц:");
    //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Вывод** программы в обоих случаях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для **угадывания** случайного элемента из массива вам подойдет такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"Cp1251"));
    System.out.println("Введите месяц:");
    //Задаем массив месяцев для ввода:
    String[] arr = {"Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль"};
    Random rand = new Random();
    //Выбираем рандомный элемент (месяц) из нашего массива:
    String s, luck = arr[rand.nextInt(arr.length)];
    boolean isLuck = false;
    //Пока не введен верно месяц с консоли, крутим цикл до посинения:
    while (!isLuck) {
        s = br.readLine();
        if (s.equals(luck)) {
            System.out.println("Верно!");
            isLuck = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Не угадали, попробуйте еще раз");
        }
    }
}
```

**Вывод:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вывод производится в консоль Windows (cmd.exe), то там кодировка CP866. Кодировка Windows-1251 может быть использована только в GUI, например в консоли самого NetBeans.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov у меня та же беда в среде Netbeans все работает [ok], а когда запускаю jar, то все - [кракозябры]. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Если запускаете в командной строке Windows, до запуска jar введите команду `chcp 1251`. Если не поможет, надо смотреть в какой кодировке ваша программа выводит сообщения, попробовать совместить вашу кодировку с кодировкой консоли Windows, т.е. исправить в коде вашей программы или попробовать исправить в консоли Windows с помощью chcp.

Comment: Возможно в консоли надо ещё шрифт поменять. Посмотрите статью, может поможет [https://pc.ru/articles/nastrojka-kodirovki-shriftov](https://pc.ru/articles/nastrojka-kodirovki-shriftov)