# Проблема с отображением русских символов в NetBeans

Tags: java, строки, netbeans, кодировка

Работаю в NetBeans

Когда я присваиваю переменной типа String значение на русском, в окне вывода вместо этого значения показывают знаки вопроса:
ввод: русс
вывод: ????

Я изменял кодировку с UTF-8 на windows-1251,но ничего не поменялось

```
вот код
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("ввод ");
String s1 = input.nextLine(); 
System.out.print("\nВывод "+s1);
```

Просто код не предлагать, т.к. у меня много других программ, а это пример.

Comment: дубль http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510456/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-netbeans ?

Comment: Вы задали вчера этот же вопрос почти слово в слово. Не надо заниматься дублированием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если смена кодировки проекта не помогла, попробуйте поменять сразу кодировку вводимых символов:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"Cp1251"));
    System.out.println("Ввод:");
    String s = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```